# WP_Query to show post from a category OR custom field - Not 100% answered

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, join-tables

Regarding answer provided by birgirethis to this post: [wp-query-to-show-post-from-a-category-or-custom-field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190011/wp-query-to-show-post-from-a-category-or-custom-field/190018#190018)

I found one issue with your solution. The two inner joins (term_relationships and postmeta) will only get results when a specific post has at least one term_relationship entry, otherwise the query won't fetch that post and will get a faulty result. How do I modify the code to get the expected results?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the "nature" of `INNER joins` used by the core here, try other types, like `LEFT` ones instead.

Comment: Thank you birgire! How do I mark this as answered??